# Update value in array()

Tags: php, arrays

For exemple I use this array:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 39584
>         [quantity] => 1
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 39584
>         [quantity] => 3
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 39574
>         [quantity] => 1
>     )
>
> [3] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 39586
>         [quantity] => 1
>     )
> ```
>
> )

My question is: How can I update "quantity" if the "id" is similar to that introduced earlier?

Example:

> Array (
>
> ```
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 39584
>         [quantity] => 4
>     )
>
> [1] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 39574
>         [quantity] => 1
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [id] => 39586
>         [quantity] => 1
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: Are the ID's that are similar always next to eachother or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($your_array as $sub_array) {
  if (empty($result[$sub_array['id']])) {
    $result[$sub_array['id']] = $sub_array;
  } else {
    $result[$sub_array['id']]['quantity'] += $sub_array['quantity'];
  }
}
```

This will group arrays by their 'id' key and sum up values

Answer (score 1):

If you need the array in this form you have to do a search.

```
foreach ($array as $set)
{
    if ($set['id'] == $checkedId)
    {
        $set['quantity'] = $newQuantity;
        return;
    }
}
```

If you can change the array, why not make the id's the keys?

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($oldArray as $set)
{
    $newArray[$set['id']] = $set['quantity'];
}
```

Now you can access quantities with `$newArray[$checkedId]`

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with some foreach loops, or you could make your life much easier by changing your array structure to be something more like this:

```
  Array (
    [39584] => 4
    [39574] => 1
  )
```

Then to add quantities, it would be as simple as:

```
$main_array[$id] = $main_array[$id] + $new_array[$id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Each array has a position already in the parent array so if you want the first set then you call it:
`$var[0][quantity]` mind you, why do you have multiple arrays with the same id?